# Tooltip does not come up after showing up 2-3 times

Tags: c#

I am using the Tooltip class like this...

where ctrl is a Picture ctrl.

ToolTip oTooltip  = new ToolTip();
 oTooltip.SetToolTip(ctrl, "The algorithm has been completed successfully");
 oTooltip.ShowAlways = true;

When the form is loaded, teh tooltip is shown... it shows up some two or three time whenever i hover the mouse obver it but from the fourth hover it stops coming/sghowing.

is there anything that i need to set.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue not too long ago. To work around the problem, I subscribed to the control's `MouseEnter` event and toggled between setting the `Active` property of the `ToolTip` from `false` to `true`. My code looked something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public Form1()
{
    this.pictureBox1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseEnter);

    this.ToolTip = new ToolTip();
    this.ToolTip.SetToolTip(this.pictureBox1, "The algorithm has been completed successfully.")
}

private ToolTip ToolTip
{
    get;
    set;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ToolTip.Active = false;
    this.ToolTip.Active = true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1: The tooltip in winforms kills me. If you hover until the tooltip disappears by itself it will never show again... And you can't increase the length of time until it disappears beyond an arbitrary low period of time.